# How do I properly include an external jar file for a cordova plugin?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to make a simple cordova android plugin that requires classes defined in a jar file. I have a test project [here](https://github.com/konsumer/testpebble), that includes the example usage & a simplified version of my plugin.

In my plugin.xml, I have this:

```
<platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Pebble">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.jetboystudio.pebble.PebblePGPlugin"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/PebblePGPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/jetboystudio/pebble" />
        <source-file src="src/android/libs/pebble_kit.jar" target-dir="libs" />
    </platform>
```

In my test project, I have pebblekit jar in-place where it needs to be (I think): plugins/com.jetboystudio.pebble.PebblePGPlugin/src/android/libs/pebble_kit.jar

When I "cordova build" I get no errors, but when I install the apk-file I get "Class not found" in Chrome device inspect. I am assuming this class it can't find is one of the classes defined in pebble_kit.jar. Also, it doesn't seem to be copying this file into platforms/android.

If I could just debug better (which class is not found?) that might be a good start, if no one has the actual answer of why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `plugin.xml` is correct.

Do not edit the `plugin.xml` after you have added/install the plugin into the project.
When you run cordova build or prepare it will not process the native parts of plugin.xml, it only get's process on cordova plugin add

Update your plugin repo/folder with `plugin.xml` containing the **jar** file and the line that you have is correct.

Then do

```
cordova plugin rm

cordova plugin add

cordova build
```

The end result verify that `/platforms/android/libs/pebble_kit.jar` is present after cordova build.

Comment: that worked to copy it, but now I get all kinds of other "cannot find symbol" errors. I upgraded java somewhere in the process, and I think it might have to do with that.

Comment: it seems to be missing refs to getApplicationContext() and JSONException which were ok, before.

Comment: ok, so I got it a little further, but still am at a loss. here is my current plugin java & build result: https://gist.github.com/konsumer/4bd186f06b29a45b99b1  I am getting "cannot find symbol" for "getApplicationContext()". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. My other issue was I need to use this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext() instead of just getApplicationContext(), now.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add a jar file with:

```
<lib-file src="src/android/libs/pebble_kit.jar" />
```

This will add the jar to `platforms/android/app/libs/`