# Nondeterministic class loading problem in jar library of android cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, classloader

I am developing an Android Cordova plugin with local JAR libraries.

The JAR libraries are copied by Cordova into my `app/libs` folder (following the answer to this question: [How do I properly include an external jar file for a cordova plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438160/how-do-i-properly-include-an-external-jar-file-for-a-cordova-plugin/25440153))

The Cordova app builds and runs but one class (`ContextFactory`), which is present in a local JAR file, fails to load:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't read Device Description(Provider ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
not found / Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory" on path: DexPathList[[directory 
"."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

At first, I had the plugin run in the standard WebCore thread. After switching to a seperate thread (via `cordova.getThreadPool().execute()`) the class sometimes loads (non-deterministically) but only when I debug with several break points active.

By debugging into the relevant place (`java.lang.ClassLoader`), the AndroidStudio debugger informs me that the classLoader is
`dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]]`

More specifically, in the AndroidStudio-decompiled bytecode of (`java.lang.ClassLoader` from SDK Android 29), the method call
`url = findResource(name);` (line 793) finds a resource non-deterministically. If `url` remains `null`, the exception will be thrown, if a `url` is found, the class loads successfully. (`url` in the good case evaluates to `jar:file:/data/app/name.of.my.app-1/base.apk!/META-INF/services/ae.javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` where `ae.javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` is another class in the JAR file)

I assume that the `"."` directory refers to `/app/` and so I wonder if I have to configure my project to include `/app/libs/` somehow as well. If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the library can be loaded if I run the plugin on the UI thread. `cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread()`